# Shell command to count lines in a file

Tags: shell, count

I have a file with 3 columns and to give a shell/bash command to know how many lines there are for each combination of the 1st and 3rd column

My file is as follows

```
COLS949 300 7
COLS949 301 7
COLS949 302 7
COLS949 302 8
COLS949 303 7
COLS949 43401 84
COLS950 303 7
```

Desired output:

```
COLS949 7 4
COLS949 8 1
COLS949 84 1
COLS950 1 7
```

So I have 4 times a line with "Cols949" in the first column and "7" in the third column etc. It does not matter if the order of columns is changed, so it is also fine to have the output as follows:

```
COLS949 4 7
COLS949 1 8
COLS949 1 84
COLS950 7 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '{a[$1 " " $3]++}END {for( i in a) print i, a[i]}' input
```